# Is there any way to use multiple yml file with nelmio_api_doc in symfony 3 with NelmioApiDocBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, swagger-editor, nelmioapidocbundle

NelmioApiDocBundle is allowing only single configuration file as .yml as.

```
nelmio_api_doc:
  routes:
    path_patterns: # an array of regexps
      - ^/api
  documentation:
    paths:
      /api/login_check:
      ...
      /api/refresh_token:
      ...
```

But I have more then 200 URL to use and all for different Bundles.
it would **working properly** but hard to handle all in same file.

So if anyone has solution to divide "paths" as different separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! :-)

One of Mine friend has a great idea to resolve this problem. actually, this is not the proper solution, but I this is the only way to solve this problem.

We create "api_index.yaml"

```
export_path: '/config/packages/api_doc.yaml'

import_paths:
  - "@DomCoreBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/api_base_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomCmsBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/static_page_path_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomEntityBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/category_path_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomCmsBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/carousel_path_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomQuickLinkBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/quick_link_path_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomUserBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/user_path_doc.yaml"
  - "@DomUserBundle/Resources/config/api_doc/dealer_path_doc.yaml"
  ...
```

Then we create a Symfony command(script) which read each "import_paths" file and append content in "export_path" file.

```
$this->io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
$path = $this->kernel->locateResource('@FaCoreBundle/Resources/config/api_index.yaml');
$paths = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($path));

if (array_key_exists('import_paths', $paths)) {
    $contentLength = $this->loadFilesByPath($input, $output, $paths);
    if ($input->getOption('watch')) {
        $contentLengthNew = [];
        while (true) {
            foreach ($paths['import_paths'] as $path) {
                $ymlPath = $this->kernel->locateResource($path);
                $contentLengthNew[$ymlPath] = md5((file_get_contents($ymlPath)));
            }

            if (!empty(array_diff($contentLength, $contentLengthNew)) || count($contentLength) != count($contentLengthNew)) {
                $diff = array_diff($contentLengthNew, $contentLength);
                if (!empty($diff)) {
                    $this->io->writeln(sprintf('<comment>%s</comment> <info>[file+]</info> %s', date('H:i:s'), current(array_keys($diff))));
                }

                $contentLength = $this->loadFilesByPath($input, $output, $paths);
            }

            sleep($input->getOption('period'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the config options "routes" and "documentation" in the [configuration reference of NelmioApiDocBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/configuration-reference.html)

You should instead use Annotations, as [described in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/the-apidoc-annotation.html).

Comment: This docs for symfony 2.x application only, but I used symfony 3.3 and Doc  for latest version of "NelmioApiDocBundle" is here : https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle

Comment: No, it's the Documentation of v2 oft the ApiDoc-Bundle. I recently migrated to Symfony 3.3 and it's working well.

Comment: No, it's working  but there are  "routes" and "documentation"  options available in doc. and API is working properly with single file and no need to change any of these.

Answer (score 0):

A simply way is to read yaml files from a not autoload area, merge the content and write a single file that will be loaded.

## SF 4.x

```
/config
    /NELMIOApiDocDefinitions // out of autowire
        /one.yaml
        /two.yaml
    /packages
        /_NELMIOApiDocDefinitions.yaml // file_put_content()
```

## one.yaml

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        path_patterns:
            - /one
    documentation:
        tags:
            - { name: One, description: '...' }
        paths:
            /onepath/:
                ...
```

## Kernel.php

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $this->mergeNELMIOApiDocYamlDefinitions();
    ...
}

private function mergeNELMIOApiDocYamlDefinitions()
{
    // dev, prod, ...
    $kernelEnvironnement = $this->getEnvironment();

    // No need to rebuild definitions in production
    if ($kernelEnvironnement == 'prod')
        return;

    // Path to the configuration directory
    $confDir = $this->getProjectDir() . '/config';

    // Path to the documentations files to merge
    $yamlDefinitionsDirectory = $confDir . '/NELMIOApiDocDefinitions';

    // Get the files to merge (without dots directories)
    $yamlDefinitionsFiles = array_diff(scandir($yamlDefinitionsDirectory), ['.', '..']);

    // Read definitions files and merge key with theirs values
    $mergedDefinitions = [];
    foreach ($yamlDefinitionsFiles as $yamlDefinitionFile) {
        $yamlFileContent = Yaml::parseFile($yamlDefinitionsDirectory . '/' . $yamlDefinitionFile);
        $mergedDefinitions = array_merge_recursive($mergedDefinitions, $yamlFileContent);
    }

    // Build the YAML
    $yaml = Yaml::dump($mergedDefinitions);

    // Write the YAML into a single file to be loaded by Symfony
    file_put_contents($confDir . '/packages/_NELMIOApiDocDefinitions.yaml', $yaml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with

**config/packages/nelmio.yaml**

```
imports:
 - {resource: '../nelmio/default.yaml'}
 - {resource: '../nelmio/v1.yaml'}
```

**config/nelmio/default.yaml**

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/default/ ]
            documentation:
                info:
                    title: Default
```

**config/nelmio/v1.yaml**

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/v1/ ]
            documentation:
                info:
                    title: V1
```